# Does the OS (CentOS) clear the temporary files automatically?

Tags: centos, operating-systems, temporary-files

Does the OS (CentOS) clear the temporary files automatically and what is the difference between `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` ?

If the system clears these files automatically, how can I change the TTL ?

Answer (score 1):

They are different:

`/tmp` is mounted since boot and cleaned between reboots.

`/var/tmp` could be unavailable during boot if `/var` is a mountpoint. It is not cleaned between reboots.

CentOS 6 has an utility called *tmpwatch*. It is being executed daily (at the time cron.daily is invoked) from the script called `/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch`.  It deletes a file if the *atime* (last accessed time) is more than 10 days ago.

In CentOS 7 it is different because it uses `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer`.